# How does UIKit draw animated UIActivityIndicator when main thread is blocked?

Tags: ios, multithreading, uikit, drawing, objective-c-blocks

Consider the code below. When this is run, the activity indicator appears and animates, and simultaneously "test" is logged to the console repeatedly. Why?

I would expect the activity indicator to appear on screen but fail to animate, because the "test" block is executed on the main queue before the next redraw of the activity indictor, and the block never finishes executing.

Is UIKit drawing the activity indicator off the main thread?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIActivityIndicatorView *v = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
  [self.view addSubview:v];
  v.center = self.view.center;
  [v startAnimating];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    while (1) {
      NSLog(@"test");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Surely any animation at all, is just implemented by Apple as a timer on another thread, which just continuously (say, 20hz, or whatever), tells the UI to change frames.

Answer (score 1):

**Core Animation Programming Guide**

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimation_guide.pdf

States that:

> Because it manipulates a static bitmap, layer-based drawing
>   differssignificantly from more traditional view-based drawing
>   techniques. With view-based drawing, changes to the view itself often
>   result in a call to the view’s drawRect: method to redraw content
>   using the new parameters. But drawing in this way is expensive because
>   it is done using the CPU on the main thread. Core Animation avoids
>   this expense by whenever possible by manipulating the cached bitmap in
>   hardware to achieve the same or similar effects.

Not all drawing will happen on the main thread.